# How to read CArchive booleans in c#

Tags: c#, c++, .net, c#-4.0, visual-c++

I have something written into carchive in C++ to be read in C#. Here is c++ code

```
CString str= "string value";
BOOL firstBool=false;
BOOL secondBool= True;
Bool thirdBool= true;
CMemFile    file(DataBlob->GetData(), dLength);
CArchive    ar(&file, CArchive::load);
ar << str<<firstBool<<secondBool<<thirdBool;
```

Here is how i read in C#

```
var br = new BinaryReader(new MemoryStream(file));                    
var strCSharp= br.ReadString();
var firstBoolCSharp= br.readBoolean();
var secondBoolCSharp= br.readBoolean();
var thirdBoolCSharp= br.readBoolean();
```

Issue: I cannot read first, second and third Boolean in c#. What could be the issue?

Comment: Not a direct answer, but I would write up a quick C++/CLI DLL that would use MFC to read the CArchive and hand off to a .Net class.

Comment: I have no knowledge of CLI can you point me other direction

Comment: To continue in @crashmstr way : Without even thinking about the CLI, you could write a little C++ dll, which would expose methods for reading the file, then you'll have to import the DLL's functions into your C# code and you're done : DllImport doc : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984739(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: You cannot use ReadString(), it only works if the string was written by BinaryWriter.  You'll have to read the string length first, that's rocket science, then the characters in the string.  Use the code in AfxReadStringLength() to get it right.

Comment: If you want to do it with only C#, you'll probably need to look at the file and make sure you are reading the correct types (i.e. `BOOL` is not a `bool` and `readBoolean` probably won't work).

Comment: @crashmstr : 
You are right BOOL is not a bool. That is the problem need to be fixed. but how in C#?

Comment: @user841612 probably need to read as an int and then test for 0/!0, but you need to look at the file to make sure that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i resolved it.

C++ writes Boolean as integer "0" or "1". Hence on the reading side of C# it should C#: `bool result= binaryReader.ReadInteger()>0;` to find out if it is true or false.

This solved my problem.